# Не работает команда Subprocess Popen

Tags: python, subprocess

Когда я выполняю команду `Popen(["python", "Messanger/clientApp.py"])`, файл не запускается, просто ничего не происходит, код идёт дальше.

Естественно, `Popen` импортирован. Передавать `shell=True` - пробовал.

Comment: он может не видеть путь, попробуйте абсолютный

Answer (score 1):

```py
from shutil import which
import subprocess as sp

sp.run(
    [which('python'), '-V']
)
```

Вывод

```latex
Python 3.9.9
```

Если проект запускается в виртальном окружении, должно сработать, и укажите полный путь до `Messanger/clientApp.py`

Comment: Ваш пример работает, версия выводится, но когда мне приходится открывать сам файл... Все также, приложение подлагивает, и всё. `sp.run([which('python'), 'absolute/path'])`

Answer (score 1):

Укажи абсолютный путь(например если файл лежит где-то в твоем домашнем каталоге /home/your_username/Messanger/clientApp.py) до clientApp.py, как указал Namerek.

Answer (score 1):

попробую еще вот так

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import subprocess
run=subprocess.Popen('python3 /home/user_name/Messanger/clientApp.py', shell=True)
```

Должно сработать, при условии, что интерпретатор питона 3 установлен в выше указанной директории и правильно пропиши путь к вызываемому файлу

Comment: Проблема оказалась в том, что код после `subprocess Popen` работает дальше, и получалось так, что сразу после `Popen` в консоль выводилось: `Для закрытия нажмите любую клавишу`, и я закрывал консоль, т. к думал что программа завершена. Но на деле, программа работала дальше, а текст об завершении - неправдивый. Что-то вроде бага.

Comment: Ну и славно что разобрался и все заработало.